# Empty table in MySQL even though Python can insert data into table

Tags: python, mysql, insert, database-table

I'm new to mySQL and Python.

I have code to insert data from Python into mySQL,

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="kokoblack", db="mydb")
for i in range(0,len(allnames)):
    try:
        query = "INSERT INTO resumes (applicant, jobtitle, lastworkdate, lastupdate, url) values ("
        query = query + "'"+allnames[i]+"'," +"'"+alltitles[i]+"',"+ "'"+alldates[i]+"'," + "'"+allupdates[i]+"'," + "'"+alllinks[i]+"')"
        x = conn.cursor()
        x.execute(query)
        row = x.fetchall()
    except:
        print "error"
```

It seems to be working fine, because "error" never appears. Instead, many rows of "1L" appear in my Python shell. However, when I go to MySQL, the "resumes" table in "mydb" remains completely empty.

I have no idea what could be wrong, could it be that I am not connected to MySQL's server properly when I'm viewing the table in MySQL? Help please.

(I only use import MySQLdb, is that enough?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use commit to commit the changes that you have done

MySQLdb has autocommit off by default, which may be confusing at first

You could do commit like this

```
conn.commit()
```

or

```
conn.autocommit(True) Right after the connection is created with the DB
```

Comment: Omg you are AWESOME, I've spent two days trying to figure out what was wrong. Thank you SO MUCH

Comment: Haha I see. Another thing is, when scraping webdata, if I only insert the data into mySQL after I've stored it all in an object, am I likely to run out of memory?